# Error en registro de fecha en formato DateTime en .net a postgres TimeZone

Tags: datetime

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Feliz tarde, tengo este problema:
soy relativamente nuevo en desarrollo. no me deja agregar los registros  porque me sale error 400

Fecha en visual se encuentra como datetime(2017/25/03 00:00:00) y en PostgreSQL como Timestamp without time zone, pero no me deja guardarlo en la base de datos por los tipos DateTime y Timestamp without time zone, que debo hacer?

en mascotaDto no esta la fecha de creación porque la hereda de mascota donde si esta la fecha de creación con formato DateTime, si comento la fecha de creación si me deja guardar el registro en la BD de[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] POSTGRES, el registro que aparece en la BD es cuando comente la fecha de creación, pero si la habilito[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS2yw.png) me genera error al insertar un registro

como soluciono el error.

public async Task Post(MascotaDTO mascotaDto)
{
try
{   var mascota = _mapper.Map(mascotaDto);
mascota.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now.Date;

```
     _context.Add(mascota);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

     var mascotaItemDto = _mapper.Map<MascotaDTO>(mascota);
     return CreatedAtAction("Get", new { id = mascotaItemDto.Id }, mascotaItemDto);

 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
     return BadRequest(ex.Message);
 }
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).